# WPF Rectangle or Polyline HitTest doesn't work

Tags: wpf, hittest

I just want point hittest in rectangle .

1)define a rectangle and add it to canvas in MainWindow_Load.

```
        rc = new Rectangle();
        rc.Width = 100;
        rc.Height = 100;
        rc.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        canvas.Children.Add(rc);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rc, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(rc, 30);
```

2)Test mouse point in Rectangle on mousedown.

```
 void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IInputElement input, input2;

        Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

       if (rc.InputHitTest(pt) != null)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
       }            
    }
```

3) this code doesn't work, same as polyline.  Any suggestion should be appreciative.

Comment: Change the background color of canvas to transparent.

Comment: Change the background color of canvas to null.

Comment: Please be aware that the position you pass to InputHitTest is relative to your MainWindow, but hit testing is done in coordinates relative to the upper left corner of the Rectangle.

Comment: I tried your code. Worked for me.